# Square root of an odd composite being irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

Is there an odd composite number $n$ such that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational?

Comment: The smallest such is $n=15$.

Comment: Any $n$ that isn't a perfect square. Lots of odd composite numbers aren't perfect squares, as @MJD's comment suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

The sufficient condition for $\sqrt n$ is irrational is $n$ be not perfect square i.e., at least one prime factor of $n$ has odd power

Comment: It is also necessary.

Comment: @lhf, I Was thinking about $$\sqrt e,\sqrt \pi$$

Comment: But $n$ is an integer here, right?

Comment: @lhf, I was trying to generalize